# Can I use UUID to identify developers in OpenStack?

Tags: openstack, uuid

I have a problem. The openstack community provide the [MySQL database dumps](http://activity.openstack.org/dash/browser/data/db) with the complete datasets.

I want to identify the same developers in different data schemas. And I find in different data schemas, there is a date file named 'people_uidentities', which provides the people id and his uuid as the
[image: pic].

Because I find many developers who have same name but have different uuids in different schemas. Take 'Thai Tran' as an example, his uuid in openstack_sourcecode and openstack_tickets are different.

uuid in openstack_sourcecode:
[image: pic]

uuid in openstack_tickets:
[image: pic]

**My question is what the generation mechanism of uuid in OpenStack is.**

**Can one person have serval uuids?**

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the answer for the general mechanism of uuid in OpenStack. But one user account can only have one uuid that refers to the account. And you can use the uuid to get the username. For example, if you are using the keystone client library (https://docs.openstack.org/python-keystoneclient/latest/using-api-v3.html):

```
from keystoneauth1.identity import v3
from keystoneauth1 import session
from keystoneclient.v3 import client
auth = v3.Password(auth_url='https://my.keystone.com:5000/v3',
                   user_id='myuserid',
                   password='mypassword',
                   project_id='myprojectid')
sess = session.Session(auth=auth)
keystone = client.Client(session=sess)
```

You have to be an admin role in the OpenStack to run the following commands:

```
user = keystone.users.get("###") # user's uuid to replace "###"
user.name
```

HTH.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I am not sure whether or not one user account only has one uuid that refers to the account. Because I find many developers who have same name but have different uuids in different schemas. Take 'Thai Tran' as an example, his uuid in openstack_sourcecode and openstack_tickets are different.